# Groups or monoids acting on logics

Tags: logic, reference-request, soft-question, group-actions

What's the right/typical way to describe a group or a monoid acting on a logic or, equivalently, the automorphisms/endomorphisms of the language of a logic that preserve the consequence relation?

---

Suppose I have a logic $S$ consisting of $L$ (for language), a set of well-formed formulas, and $\vdash_S$, a consequence relation. For the purposes of this question, I'm not peering inside the logic, it's just a set of sequences of symbols and a consequence relation.

Let's consider the case of classical propositional calculus.

I'll use the term "symmetry" to refer to an intuitive, preformal notion of symmetry.

Logics seem to have a lot of symmetry, in particular the following map $g$ is bijective on $L$ and preserves the consequence relation $\vdash_S$.

$$ g(\varphi) = \varphi \; \text{with every subexpression $a \land b$ replaced with $b \land a$} $$

This map is interesting because $\varphi \vdash_S g(\varphi)$ is true for all $\varphi$.

Another example of a symmetry is $f$, defined below.

$$ f(\varphi) = \varphi \; \text{with all occurrences of the variables $P$ and $Q$ swapped} $$

In this case, $\varphi \vdash_S f(\varphi)$ is not always true since $P \vdash_S Q$ is false.

It seems fairly clear that we can collect all the automorphisms of $L$ (with $\vdash_S$ being the structure that they have to respect) into a group.

It also seems clear that that we can collect each endomorphism $e$ of $L$ satisfying the rule below into a monoid. Let $\Phi_I$ be a family of well-formed formulas indexed by $I$.

$$ \Phi_I \vdash_S \varphi \implies \{ e(\Phi_i) : i \in I \} \vdash_S e(\varphi) $$

There are two semi-interesting monoids I can think of, the one that sends everything to $\top$ and the one that sends everything to $\bot$.

So far, though, I haven't been able to find anything relevant for groups or monoids acting on a logic or for endomoprhisms or automorphisms of a logic, which makes me think I'm describing what sort of thing I'm after in a nonstandard/weird way.

Comment: Just a note: All variables are free in propositional calculus.

Comment: Good point. Fixed.

Comment: Even stronger, you can replace any (free) variable with any statement everywhere. So $p\lor(\lnot p)$ we can replace all occurrences of $p$ with $p\lor q.$

Comment: I suppose replacing $p$ with $p\land q$ only satisfies one direction. It is possible for the result of the operation to be true but not the input. For example $p\to(p\land q)$ is not provable, but $(p\land q)\to((p\land q)\land q)$ is, so it depends on what you mean by “preserves” the relation $\vdash.$

Comment: I meant that, for the case of groups and a given map $f$, $\Phi \vdash \psi$ holds if and only if $f(\Phi) \vdash f(\psi)$ holds and $f$ is a bijection on the set of well-formed formulas. $f(\psi)$ might have the same truth conditions as $\psi$ or it might not, the consequence relation is the only structure that I want to insist on for the individual maps.

Comment: Ah, but requiring a bijection is also stronger than I was interpreting. General substitution is not bijective. I’d consider maps of posets rather than maps of groups - $\vdash$ is much more like $\leq$ than it is like group operations.

Comment: True, that's why I threw in the bit about monoid actions as well. I'm trying to ask two parallel questions about group actions and monoid actions. Although if there are interesting constraints we can impose on monoid actions that don't amount to defining group actions, I'd like to hear about those too.

Comment: I’d consider maps of partially ordered sets as the analogy, rather than maps of groups. $\vdash$ is much more like $\leq$ than it is like group operations.

Comment: The group and monoid actions are supposed to be a convenient way of talking about subgroups of the automorphism group of $S$ and submonoids of the monoid of endomorphisms, respectively. I think I'm using the jargon right, but I'm not sure.